# Typescript infer type by sibling property

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a framework with typescript.
and I need a compile time data check.

#### My typescript interface code

```js
type TypeInfo = 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean';

type GetType<T extends TypeInfo> = T extends 'string'
  ? string
  : T extends 'number'
  ? number
  : T extends 'boolean'
  ? boolean
  : never;

interface StateInfo {
  // TypeInfo
  type: TypeInfo;
  default: GetType<this['type']>;
}
```

#### Expected (compile time)

```js
// OK
const test1: StateInfo = {
  type: 'number',
  default: 1,
};

// Bad ('default' property is not number or 'type' property is not 'string') 
const test2: StateInfo = {
  type: 'number',
  default: 'test',
};
```

But, the typescript compile the code without any errors.
How can I declare type of `'default'` property correctly?

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

`GetType<this['type']>` is evaluated during declaration of `StateInfo`. What I mean is that, the type of  `default` will be `string | number | boolean` and will not be affected by the value of property `type` while creating objects.

### Solution

Use [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)

```js
type StateInfoString = {
  type: 'string'
  default: string
}

type StateInfoNumber = {
  type: 'number'
  default: number
}

type StateInfoBoolean = {
  type: 'boolean'
  default: boolean
}

type StateInfo = StateInfoString | StateInfoNumber | StateInfoBoolean

// OK
const test1: StateInfo = {
  type: 'number',
  default: 1,
};

// error
const test2: StateInfo = {
  type: 'number',
  default: 'test',
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIEkB2AzA9nATgS1QHMoBeKAbwCgopRIAuKAcgGdh8inqoATCdeAFcANsEZsOhSgF9KlOtDiIUGTADlBAWwBGEHKQrcFjJqi26cXGnwEixUMzr0y5C2AiRosAIUyZhEPCoBlQ0xszafgFBVrz8QqKMkf6BqC7y4IoeKlgGSp6quATEAD7uyl7q5npQZfk5mL4pQXIA9K1QAPIA0pQAxpiobLQQbACMjPWVIUaZJo4WTAA03DYJ9mMr0gDcbR16OJg4-YPDSGwATJPZ02ShtHPMC3rLq-F2JufArztAA)

Comment: I would also add, that if you want to infer smth, you can also use functions with generic arguments

Comment: @captain-yossarian I didn't get it.

Comment: I added explanation, maybe I wasn't clear enough

Comment: Here's how `StateInfo` union could be generated from map like type using distributive conditional types https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEGcoF4oG8BQUoOAJwEsA7AcwC4d9iSAaLKIgVwFsAjCPCptju7VgPYCANhACGRCoJHiidAL4YMoSFADiEIhzHAIAZWA6IASSIAzAQB4A0gD4UUa1AgAPXUQAmSANYQQAs1h4JAB+dCgVCAprAG4oDwgzMUZhYAo4SAQAbWsAXSh5KC4IADcOJUioAyNTCwcNLTwjat1aq19-QIzEWyA

Answer (score 2):

@Shivam Singla 's answer is perfectly valid and I believe should be accepted. Please treat my answer as add-on )

If you want to infer smth, the best way, I believe, to use function with generics:

```js
type TypeInfo = 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean';

type GetType<T extends TypeInfo> = T extends 'string'
    ? string
    : T extends 'number'
    ? number
    : T extends 'boolean'
    ? boolean
    : never;

interface StateInfo {
    // TypeInfo
    type: TypeInfo;
    default: GetType<this['type']>;
}

const test = <T extends TypeInfo>(arg: T, prop: GetType<T>): StateInfo => {
// this return valu is just a mock, you should provide here your valid code
    return null as any
}

const result = test('string','str') // ok
const result2 = test('number',1) // ok
const result3 = test('boolean', true) // ok

const result4 = test('boolean', 1) // expected error
const result5 = test('string', false) // expected error
```

Now, your `StateInfo` is doing what you want.

Comment: Mind-blowing!! I would have never thought this way!

Comment: Though there is one problem. While accessing the property `default`, the type of the variable assigned will be `string | number | boolean`

Comment: @ShivamSingla I did not understand. I have provided 5 test cases. You are unable to create invalid obj

Comment: Consirder `const defaultValue = result.default`, the type of `defaultValue` is `string | number | boolean`. It should have been `string` only not the union type.

Comment: The trick is ok when creating objects, but while accessing/using those object, it causes the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my bad, did not check it. We have to add generic arg to StateInfo or use overloadings. Like I said, treat my answer as addon to yours.